# ggplot with points and plots of certain columns

Tags: r, ggplot2

Let's say I have a data.frame of three columns:

```
x <- seq(1,10)
y <- 0.1*x^2
z <- y+rnorm(10,0,10)
d <- data.frame(x,y,z)
```

I now want a ggplot that plots the points `(x,z)` and somewhat smooth lines going through `(x,y)`.
How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
"%>%" <- magrittr::"%>%"

d %>%
  ggplot2::ggplot(ggplot2::aes(x=x)) + 
  ggplot2::geom_point(ggplot2::aes(y=z)) + 
  ggplot2::geom_smooth(ggplot2::aes(y=y))
```

[image]

Comment: You can specify the non-base libraries used in your code.

Comment: I think I did when I was using ggplot2::

Comment: What about `%>%`? I think better to call `library(tidyverse)` which includes `ggplot2` with `magrittr`.

Comment: true, I forgot about that. Thanks :) ...  I don't like to call library() ... it can lead to conflicts and makes it harder to understand the connections between functions and packages

Comment: The question's somewhat ambiguous, but I'm not sure whether the question wanted extra smoothing (`geom_smooth()` as you wrote) or to simply plot that smooth data (which would replace `geom_smooth` with `geom_line`)